# How to get my css list to be responsive

Tags: jquery, css, html, navigation, responsive

I currently have a navigation that has multiple levels. I am trying to get it to go responsive. I am only using css and list with a small bit of jquery. Below is the full coding. Can someone help me with the responsive part.
Here is a working page showing the coding and all"

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
 jQuery('.toggle-nav').click(function(e) {
 jQuery(this).toggleClass('active');
 jQuery('nav ul').toggleClass('active');
 e.preventDefault();
});
});
```

```css
body{
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0;}

nav{
width: 100%;
background: #f2f2f2;
text-transform: lowercase;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
font: 10pt Calibri;
text-align: center;}

.toggle-nav{
display: none;
text-align: left;}

nav ul {
display: inline-block;
text-align: center;}

nav li {
display: inline-block;
list-style: none;
font: 12pt Calibri;
padding: 0px 10px;}

nav ul ul{  
display: none; 
position: absolute; 
top: 100%;
height: auto;
text-align: left;
min-width: 2em;
padding: 4px 0;
background-color: #f4f4f4;
visibility: visible;
height: 100%;}

nav ul ul:after{
content: "";
z-index: -9999;
}

nav ul ul > li{ 
padding: 5px; 
height: auto; 
background-color: #f4f4f4; 
padding: 12px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;}

nav ul ul > li a { 
background-color: #f4f4f4;
display: block;}

nav ul ul > li a:hover {
color: 0099ff; 
display: block;}

nav a {  
cursor: pointer; 
display: block; 
color:  #00bfff; 
line-height: 30px; 
padding: 0 10px; 
text-decoration: none;}

nav a:hover{
cursor: pointer;
display: block;
color: #0099ff;
line-height: 30px;
padding: 0 10px;}

nav ul li { list-style: none; }
nav ul li:hover { background: #f2f2f2;  }  
nav ul li:hover ul{ display: block; text-align: left;  } 

@media screen and (max-width: 460px) {
nav {
display: inline-block;
text-align: left;
padding: 10px;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
z-index: 9999;}

nav ul.active {
display: none;}

nav ul {
position: absolute;
top: 75%;
left: 0%;
padding: 5px 15px;
background:#e6f2ff;
text-align: left;}

nav li {
margin: 5px 15px;
float: none;
display: block; }

nav a {
display: block;
color: #00264d;}

nav li a:hover {
color: #0066cc;}

.toggle-nav {
padding: 5px -10px 25px 0px;
display: inline-block;
color: #00264d;
font-size: 1.5em;}

.toggle-nav:hover, .toggle-nav.active {
text-decoration: none;
color: #0066cc;}
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<title>Responsive Dropdown</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<nav>
<ul class="active">
<li><a href="#">About</a></li>
<li class="dropdown"><a href="#">Categories &#9662;</a>
 <ul>
  <li><a href="#">motherhood</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">lifestyle</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">writing</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">online</a></li>
 </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Links</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
</ul>
<a class="toggle-nav" href="#">Menu &#9776;</a>
</nav>



</body>
</html>
```

I would greatly appreciate the help. The navigation is to be a fixed nav at the top of the page. I know how to get that part working. It is just the responsive part that is throwing me off. Is there a css code that I am missing. Is there away to avoid using all jquery or javascript. My knowledge is not strong in that department. Again, thank you for your help!

Comment: Are you referring to animation? Like: (https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp) & (https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp).

Edit: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp

Comment: No, I am just wanting plain and simple, so that I can easily edit it and change it when need to.

Comment: When you say "responsive" you need to be more specific. Describe the effects you are looking to achieve vis a vis the effects you are seeing now.

Comment: As of right now, when the page is loaded, the navigation formals horizontal with the dropdown performing under the right spot. However, when I go to mobile, my dropdown is below everything when I want it to be below categories but above links.